# Cosmos DB Data Source - How to configure the Key in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-analysis-services

In Visual Studio I've created a Tabular Model that has a Cosmos DB Data Source.

If in Visual Studio I process the model the Data Source connects to Cosmos DB and I can browse the data in Excel.
I have successfully deployed the model to Azure Analysis Services, but quite correctly the deployment did not deploy the Cosmos DB Key, making my database effectively inaccessible.

I have tried:

1. Within Azure add the key to the Data Source.  There is nowhere in the Azure UI to do this.
2. From SSMS edit the Data Source.  You are prompted to enter the Cosmos DB Key, but SSMS throws an exception.
3. From SSMS execute an XMLA command to add the Cosmos DB Key to the Data Source, I've trawled MSDN for the property that needs to be set but cannot find what I need.

How do I deploy the key to the database so that Azure can use it?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to repro your issue.

I am able to create Tabular Model that has a Cosmos DB Data Source in visual studio. It just give below warning which adding CosmosDB as data source. However, it still add the data source.

[image]

I am able to deploy model to Azure Analysis Service with cosmosDB key.

[image]

I am able to connect to Analysis service in SSMS and able to refresh CosmosDB Key without any issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

what exception you see when using you edit data source and enters Cosmos DB key using SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.

As you stated, the 'fix' is using SSMS to ***Refresh*** the Connection.

If you try using SSMS to edit the Connection properties then this does not work.